# How to get the POST value from Javascript AJAX call to php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here is the Javascript AJAX code:

```
var anything=document.getElementById("textarea").val;
```

I have Javascript AJAX implemented:

```
httpRequest.open('POST',anyURL,true);
http.send(anything);
```

Now, my question is since this is the post data, and this is not actually associated with any html tag or id, how do I receive this in php?

```
<?php 

    $parameter=$_POST['   '];

?>
```

What should I put in the white space there?

Comment: `http_get_request_body()` or `file_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: Is the textarea generated via Javascript?

Comment: No, textarea is static, and is present in html file already.

Comment: I added an answer, but it may need to be changed based on what you're actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new variable and use JSON.stringify on your anything variable that was turned into a key value pair.

```
var anything={myTextArea: document.getElementById("textarea").value};
var JSONstr = JSON.stringify(anything);
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
    $parameter=$_POST['JSONstr'];
?>
```